# How to put text or number inside radio button in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button

I am just creating a page but on that page, I need `RadioButtons` So I want to know how to put numbers inside a `RadioButton`.

[image]

Comment: Those are not necessary radio buttons. You can achieve the same behaviour by creating a custom view with simple buttons inside it, and handle the tap on each button and deselect the others when one is selected.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any code snippet?

Comment: Thanks to all for reply

Comment: i have found solution of this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simply add button.
2. Set background as custom background as per your wish.
3. Handle that button click event.

Comment: Thanks i did this is work for me